# Which site for question about GLSL code?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about specific GLSL code and why it behaves like it does. I wanted to ask it on [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), but their rules say "Don't ask anything that it is not directly related to games."

My GLSL code is not about game graphics, it is about rendering fractals. How can I determine which Stack Exchange site is the best for asking this question? For this example, can I ask it on Stack Overflow, or is there better site for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On [Computer Graphics Stack Exchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) questions about computer graphics code (including [GLSL](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glsl)) are on topic and welcome. This covers fixing code that is not behaving as intended, reviewing working code for style and efficiency, and asking about algorithms.

As with any Stack Exchange site, please mention what you have tried so far, and for broken code provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you are uncertain whether a particular question will be on topic, or how to ask, feel free to drop in to [The Cornell Box](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/the-cornell-box), our chat room. I can always be reached there using @trichoplax to get my attention.

---

*Note that chat requires reputation of at least 20 on any Stack Exchange site. Reputation earned here on Meta Stack Exchange (although not on the individual Meta sites) counts towards this .*

Answer (score 3):

If you have a GLSL programming question, where your actual result is different than what your expect or want, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

If you are looking for improvements or optimizations on your **working** existing shader code, your question may be on topic for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Be sure to read the help center on both sites for an in-depth description as to what types of questions are on-topic.

Comment: There are [over 4,000 questions tagged `glsl` at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsl).

Comment: @AlE. right, so it would appropriate to post there if the question was asked with an MVCE and if it was in-scope for the site.  If the question asked "Here's my shader, why does it render like this?" it would probably be closed.